# nsformatter and decimal number

Tags: nsformatter

I m using nSformatter for a calculator app. 
When computing, for example : 6 divided by 10 , nsformatter gives me :   .6  instead of the much desired 0.6  . 
For decimal numbers smaller than 1 , the 0 is omitted by NS formatter.
Of course, I wrote a couple of lines to append the resulting string with a 0 but my question is :
Is there an option in Nsformatter , to achieve the desired result ?

No more    .6  but   0.6  ?

Thank you all

Answer (score 0):

OK  seem to have found a simple solution with adding this

[formatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];

working fine now .

Bye Bye